# ¿php ftp_delete can remove folder?

Tags: php, ftp

The question is: can PHP `ftp_delete()` remove a folder?
I have a process that uses `ftp_delete()` for removing ftp files but I fear I might accidentally remove a folder if the filename is empty.

Comment: `ftp_delete() deletes the file specified by path from the FTP server.`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-delete.php

Comment: Only files or also folders?

Comment: @cristiancamilocedeñogallego It deletes only files. `rmdir()` is the one that removes a folder. Edit: I stand corrected. as stated in another answer http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rmdir.php also removes folders, but I think this isn't what the question is about, it's more about clarification.

Comment: @cristiancamilocedeñogallego I didn't have time to re-edit my comment above. If you intend on deleting a folder at a later date, you can use either.

Answer (score 4):

From the manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-delete.php

*"ftp_delete() deletes the **file** specified by path from the FTP server."*

It doesn't delete a folder, `rmdir()` does.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php

*"rmdir — Removes directory"*

**Note:**

> *Attempts to remove the directory named by dirname. The directory must be empty, and the relevant permissions must permit this. A E_WARNING level error will be generated on failure.*

Comment: @IanPudney yes I know that. I simply stated that `rmdir()` deletes a folder; it's just for clarification. Edit: you deleted your comment I was answering to.

Answer (score 1):

1.-You need to check the docs, the answer is there.

2.- http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-delete.php According to the docs, no. It says "files" not "files or folders", I think the final answer is no.

Comment: On Linux, there's a common saying: *"Everything's a file."* It does turn out that `ftp_delete` won't delete folders, but I wouldn't take the lack of the text "files and folders" in documentation to mean "only real files."

Comment: Nope, I just tested the function by myself in Linux but doesn't delete folders, only files. If the file is not found, return false.

Comment: I'm not saying you were wrong (you weren't). I'm just saying that "deletes files" does not neccessarily imply "does not delete folders".

Comment: I know, don't worry, I was just clearing the things.

Answer (score 1):

No, it cannot. You need to use `ftp_rmdir` to delete folders.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rmdir.php

**Note:**

> *The directory to delete. This must be either an absolute or relative path to an **empty** directory.*